# Sharing Cookies Between Sub Domains in java?

Tags: java, cookies, jakarta-ee

I have some cookies stored in http://sub1.myserver.com
and I want to be able to see them in http://myserver.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to do it using the following code:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("myCookie", "myValue");
cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60);
cookie.setDomain(".myserver.com");
```

Comment: You did not set the domain on the resetting cookie.  The domain must match, or the browser will treat them as separate cookies.  Also, on SO you should open a new question instead of posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: Its acceptable to answer your own question. That's why SO allows it :)

Answer (score 7):

When you set the cookies from sub1.myserver.com, you must specify a domain of "myserver.com" -- this will instruct the browser to send the cookies to myserver.com and all subdomains.

Comment: please advise with my answer below.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong and you need a dot in front as in `.myserver.com`