# Java setting cookie on root path

Tags: java, cookies

I have a login page at `myhost:8080/auth/login` after I logged in I set a cookie by my home controller class which is at `'myhost:8080/home/`

I am setting my cookie like this

```
 Cookie myCookie =  new Cookie("__JSSESSIONID", request.getSession().getId());
 myCookie.setPath("/");
 response.addCookie(myCookie);
```

but when I see it via firebug, it shows me the path "/home". I want to set cookie on root path so that can ready from other places.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538484/sharing-cookies-between-sub-domains-in-java

Comment: not helpful... I am asking how to set a cookie on root path of domain

Comment: Hi @coure2011, how you solved this problem at last? Can you please share?

Comment: @coure2011  can you please share what you have done to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need:

```
<Context ... sessionCookiePath="/" > ... </Context>
```

Check [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration) for more details