# Weird issue around cookie domains and subdomains

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, dns, subdomain

I have a technical issue around cookie domains and sub-domains. Because of using CloudFront, we don't get the user agent. I have to get the user agent using JavaScript/Ajax call to server side (using Java) passing user-agent from JavaScript.

But the cookie gets set using the parent domain xyz.co.uk and this cookie needs to be accessed from our mobile website which starts with m.xyz.co.uk. I need either the cookie to be set with domain name m.xyz.co.uk or mobile website should be able to access the cookie set by parent domain.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4538484/2231632

Comment: Not exactly. It is the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cookie key domain as `.xyz.co.uk` instead of `xyz.co.uk`. This will allow the subdomain to read the cookie.